# how to write a loop condition for to get the sub sub folders name in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, loops, for-loop, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to get the folders name which are in the subfolders.

Example:

```
folder_id  folder_name parent_folder_id
      1             F1      0
      2             F2      1
      3             F3      2
      4             F4      3
```

Now I am trying to get the f4 name along with the parent folder name like :F1/F2/F3/F4
I  am getting the parent_folder_id based on folder_id and wrote the loop condition,Here is my function.

```
for vrecord in (select parent_folder_id from public."VOfficeApp_filefolder"
                  where folder_id = ip_folder_id)
loop        
            
       return query
      select (SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(b))) FROM
             (select folder_name from public."VOfficeApp_filefolder"
                  where folder_id = v_id)b)as path;
```

end loop;

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions do not build hierarchical results; for that you need a [RECURSIVE CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/queries-with.html). Once the  hierarchy is built you can then convert to json. The following function does that. The function takes the folder name you are interested in, after all it only used `at the last minuet` anyway to eliminate the rest of the hierarchy that as built.

```
create or replace function path_to_folder(target_folder_name text) 
  returns json
 language sql 
as $$ 
    with recursive folder_path (id, folder_name, path) as 
         ( select folder_id, folder_name,folder_name || '/' 
             from folders
            where parent_folder_id = 0
            union all
            select f.folder_id, f.folder_name, fp.path || f.folder_name || '/' 
              from folders f 
              join folder_path fp on (f.parent_folder_id = fp.id)
         )
       , bjc (folder_name, path) as 
         ( select folder_name, path 
             from folder_path 
            where folder_name = target_folder_name
         ) -- select * from bjc; 
    select json_agg(row_to_json((folder_name, path)))
      from bjc
     group by folder_name; 
$$;
```

Note: the second cte bjc (Before Json Conversion) is probably not needed, but as I hate json (imho a complexity I'd rather not deal with). You could move the where clause from it into the json construction. But I always like to see results before converting.

**Side Note:**  
Postgres 9.2 is obsolete. Having gone out of support in Nov, 2017. You seriously should update.